# Nginx reverse proxy issue for 4xx response code

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, 400

I have configured nginx to proxy the request that comes to the port 8000, to route to a different ip. In the configuration i also add Access-control-Allow-Origin header. This works fine if server is responding with 2xx response codes. But if server responds with 4xx response codes, It does not include the header mentioned below

```
server {
listen *:8000;

ssl                     on;
ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/axis.crt;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/axisPrivate.key;
server_name             website.com;
ssl_protocols           SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers             ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass https://api;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_intercept_errors off;  
# Simple requests
    if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST|PUT)") {
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "https://website.com";
    }

    # Preflighted requests
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  "https://website.com";
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET,PUT,POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin";
      return 200;
    }

}
}

upstream api {
 server ip:port;
}
```

Since the header is missing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin, browser is blocking any action to be performed on the response.

Error log in the browser :

```
POST https://website.com:8000/employee 409 ()
EmployeeRegistration:1 Failed to load https://website.com:8000/employee: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'https://website.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 409.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [intended behavior](https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html):

> Syntax:    **add_header** *name value* [always];
>
> Default:   —
>   Context:    http, server, location, if in location
>
> Adds the specified field to a response header provided that the response code equals 200, 201 (1.3.10), 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, 307 (1.1.16, 1.0.13), or 308 (1.13.0). The value can contain variables.
>
> There could be several `add_header` directives. These directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no `add_header` directives defined on the current level.
>
> If the `always` parameter is specified (1.7.5), the header field will be added regardless of the response code.

You need the **always** keyword in the `add_header` directive.